# Distribution of scalar product of correlated unitary vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two $N$-dimensional complex normal Gaussian vectors $x,y$, i.e., each element in $x$ and $y$ is complex, with mean 0 and complex variance 1. Moreover, they have a certain complex correlation matrix $E\{xy^{\ast}\} = \Gamma$, where $\ast$ is Hermitian transpose. Now let $z = x^{\ast}y/(\|x\|\|y\|)$, where $\|.\|$ denotes the Frobenius norm. What is the distribution of $z$?